# 403 on new web application

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-403

I've just installed IIS on my machine and tried to create a simple default page site.
On the creation of the project the VS said that it could not configure the server and I sould do it manually.
I opened IIS and "created" the site and gave it a name
I also changed the security tab to allow anonymous access, and the asp.net version to 2.0

when i try to browse to the site i get 403

Comment: Is the error just 403 or 403.X?  If it is the later can you edit the reponse with full error code.  Also, have a look at the IIS Error Logs, the full error should be in there if it is not reported back to browser.

Comment: What operating system are you using; xp, vista 7 ? Do standard HTML files render ok in your project folder? if not are you running skype or something else that blocks port 80.

Comment: Make sure IIS has permissions to the filesystem location of the web root - NTFS permissions can easily cause a 403.

Comment: Hold on a minute, why the hell has this been bumped up, three years after being asked, by an unrelated editor making a trivial tag related edit?  Ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

A 403 means "Forbidden", see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), but this can have different causes...

Maybe ASP.NET is not enabled on your server?
See [this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/44f16c37-f727-4244-9813-2289e13dadba.mspx?mfr=true) for more information...

Answer (score 0):

Is the folder in your My Documents? Try moving it outside there, the stuff in your user profile isn't necessarily accessible to IIS.